# Why data bind template is not working on 2.2 or greater?

Tags: template, knockoutjs, frontend-error

I was studying about Knockout.js and how it works with Magento 2.

Then I reached the topic: template integration, in the first sample of it I'm presented to this notation:

```
<div data-bind="template:'Namespace_Module/sample'"></div>
```

Which will try to render the template located at:

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/template/sample.html
```

It's working in Magento versions equals/lower than 2.1.

In greater versions it's throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return 'Namespace_Module/sample' }"
Message: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at RemoteTemplateEngine.makeTemplateSource (engine.js:55)
    at RemoteTemplateEngine.renderTemplate (engine.js:116)
    at executeTemplate (knockout.js:4886)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhen (knockout.js:4950)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at Object.ko.renderTemplate (knockout.js:4942)
    at update (knockout.js:5080)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
```

I was trying to understand why it's happening looking for the change in github, but it's not clear to me:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d99043c097816388b2aeec1c23e10bf15e064b28#diff-9ec27f11f8253078a99c9d1e979a07f3

Now it requires a bindingContext (which contain the name attribute requested in exception) but I don't know how it's initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears a UI Component is now required for KnockoutJS component initialization, due to changes in their custom renderer.

There's a lot of boiler to set this up, but you would:

- Add a `jsLayout` argument to your layout block, defining the name of your component and KnockoutJS template

`app/code/Macademy/KoTest/view/frontend/layout/kotest_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="ko.test" template="Macademy_KoTest::ko-test.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="ko-test" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Macademy_KoTest/js/ko-test</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Macademy_KoTest/my-knockout-template</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Create your UI component

`app/code/Macademy/KoTest/view/frontend/web/js/ko-test.js`

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function(
    Component
) {
    'use strict';

    console.log('ko-test UI Component has been loaded');


    // You'd normally always return Component.extend(), then pass the
    // configuration as JSON into this parent class.

    return Component;
});
```

- Then create your PHTML file, bound to the scope of your UI Component, which can then display the template defined in your XML (or hardcoded, etc)

`app/code/Macademy/KoTest/view/frontend/templates/ko-test.phtml`

```
<?php /* @var $block Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */ ?>

<div id="ko-test" data-bind="scope: 'ko-test'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#ko-test": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note that you just wanted to display the Knockout template, and nothing else, you can replace `Macademy_KoTest/js/ko-test` with `uiComponent` in the XML file and not even have to create a custom UI component file, but usually you are doing more than just displaying a template file.

The instantiation is a bit different from KnockoutJS's, as the default looks for rendered templates on the page, while Magento's looks for file paths https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#template

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same exact issue while following Alan Storm's KnockoutJs integration article.

I saw the following on another one of his articles (https://alanstorm.com/knockoutjs_primer_for_magento_developers/):

```
<div id="one" data-bind="template:{'name':'hello-world','data':first}"></div>
```

I haven't gotten it working yet, but perhaps this is the way to initialize the name attribute? Hopefully someone with more knowledge of magento2 can chime in with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same issue and solved it by this way..

**Change your content.phtml like this**

```
<div id="custom-component" data-bind="scope:'customcomponent'">
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   custom-component": {
      "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
          "components": {
             "customcomponent": {
                "component": "Namespace_Module/js/custom-component"
                                }
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }
        </script>
     </div>
```

**Create custome component in Namespace/module/view/frontend/web/js/custom-component.js with code**

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko'], function ($, Component, ko) {
         'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Namespace_module/hello'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        }
    });
}
```

);

clear cache and reload your page it starts working..Hope it helps any new learne